# Share json file to dropbox / one drive / google drive on an ios react-native app

Tags: react-native

I am writing an react-native ios application which generates text file. The file is stored at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/76C594FD-282D-41B2-9BE6-B6B1C785BDE6/Documents/backup.json using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs).

I want to share this file to google drive/dropbox/microsoft one drive so I use the ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions API to share the file:

```
  ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions({
      url: '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/76C594FD-282D-41B2-9BE6-B6B1C785BDE6/Documents/backup.json'
    },
    (error) => console.warn(error.message),
    (success, method) => {
      var text;
      if (success) {
        text = 'Shared';
      } else {
        text = 'Not shared';
      }
      console.warn(text)
    })
```

but the share actions do not include either of google drive/onedrive/dropbox when I test on the device ([screenshot available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25ClJ.png)).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you found any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the device doesn't actually have google drive or dropbox installed. If those apps aren't installed, they won't be options for you to share to.